# qnx run error : Attempting to exec a shared lib

Tags: c, qnx, qnx-neutrino, momentics

I managed to setup the Neutrino 6.5.0 RTOS in a virtual box and connect to it over qconn from Momentics IDE for Blackberry IDE 2.1.2 .....
I can get the system information perspective view for my Neutrino.

BUT

when I am trying to run my compiled application I am getting the errors :

Could not launch
Cannot find qnx launch process

and

Error starting remote application.
Target launcher@<192.168.56.101:8000>: Error: Attempting to exec a shared lib

SO I manually copied the executable file I compiled to the /tmp dir on my Neutrino virtual machine and run it using ./Test  ,still get this error:
"/bin/sh: ./Test: Attempting to exec a shared lib"

I rechecked the project option and make sure that this is an Application output and not a shared library output type.

Any idea what am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered the same problem. Later, I found that the cross compiler was selected incorrectly. This error occurs when x86 programs are run on arm processors; Specify the correct compiler to solve the problem;